# Django order events by calendar date instead of date posted

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a newsletter home page that has an events calendar on the side. Sometimes events come up and I need to insert them between two other events. Is there a way I can do this automatically in Django? I know how to order by date posted - for things like blog posts - but I don't see anywhere in the docs how to do this by actual calendar date. This is the code from my view:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = NewsLetter
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def events(self):
        return Event.objects.all()


class PastEventView(ListView):
    model = PastEvent
    template_name = 'events.html'
    ordering = ['event_date']
```

Model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    website_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    event_date = models.DateField('MM/DD/YYYY',
                                  auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

The past events is alright, but I don't know how to code the order by for the events function under the HomeView class.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to insert date field in the template?

Comment: I have updated my code to include the model. I am trying to order the events by event_date. I am not sure how to do that, because events are set as a method under the HomeView class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 1
    model = NewsLetter
    template_name = 'home.html'
    ordering = ['-post_date']

    def events(self):
        return Event.objects.order_by('event_date')
```